# how to save mysql dumps for N days?

Tags: backup, mysql, dump

Is there any best practice for saving mysql-dumps daily backups for 30 days and then delete them, without writing scripts that checks date and delete?

maybe a builtin tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logrotate` for that. A sample logrotate configfile could look something like this, assuming that you use a cronjob to save a daily mysql-dump in `/home/myuser/mysqldumps/mydb.sql`:

```
/home/myuser/mysqldumps/mydb.sql {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 31
        notifempty
}
```

Adding `compress` can be considered to reduce diskspace.